# Reputation tab really lagging today

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar

I've today just got 45 rep so far.

But when I got them the total reputation just changes on the top right corner... But there is no green tab with +10 or +15.

And after around 20 minutes, I saw the +10s and +15s coming in, but it wasn't new reputation, instead it was the reputation from like 20 minutes ago.

I got reputation so far from the following posts:

[How to repeat a string multiple times with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68960424/how-to-repeat-a-string-multiple-times-with-spaces/68960435#68960435)

[comparing one column from a Dataframe to another of different sizes in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68960369/comparing-one-column-from-a-dataframe-to-another-of-different-sizes-in-pandas/68960394#68960394)

But the reputation from those posts are coming way later...

I think this is a new bug... Yesterday wasn't like this